Google sheet Filter + Match?
I have 2 different reports which I am trying to match the invoice no. in sheet 2 to sheet 1 in google sheet. It is impossible to clean the transaction description column.
I had try to combine Match and Filter function to match but it does not seem to work
Example sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vmgQlbe6HnwWYPlomCO6GAqWg5QrzohE/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=116088573409775464472&rtpof=true&sd=true
The documents i'm working on has over 1000 rows, I'd rather not manually do this if at all possible.
Please assist, thank you.
The formula i tried is in Sheet1 C2. I am trying to achieve Column C in Sheet'End result'

You can use:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",1,Sheet2!A2:A))&B2:B,{Sheet2!A2:A&Sheet2!B2:B,Sheet2!C2:C},2,0)))


Hi Z, i tried the above formula, it worked for the sample but when i tried on my actual dataset, it did not work.  I had updated my google sheet, could you take a look Example sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vmgQlbe6HnwWYPlomCO6GAqWg5QrzohE/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=116088573409775464472&rtpof=true&sd=true

if in Sheet1 column 1 there isn't an occurrence of a full name found in Sheet2 I'm afraid it's not optimal to solve this using a formula/script as there would be too many cases to consider.
